# Pegar nomes de um form em uma página php e colocar em uma lista do tipo select em outra página php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Possuo 2 páginas `cadastrar_loja.php` e `cadastra_documento.php`. Em `cadastrar_loja.php` existe um campo de texto chamado `Nome da loja`, gostaria de pegar esse nome, do banco de dados, e inserir em um `<select>` na página `cadastrar_documento.php`. Criando assim uma lista dentro do `<select>` com todos os nomes das lojas cadastradas.

A aplicação é em `PHP` e meu banco é `mysql`, estou rodando no `xampp`.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Sim é possível fazer isso, tem algum código? começou?

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao SOPT  @Túlio, Teria como [edit] seu post e acrescentar o código que esta utilizando, assim podemos analisar e sugerir uma alteração. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está usando mysql (aconselho a estudar sobre **mysqli** ou **PDO**), primeiro faça o select da tabela `cadastrar_loja` na página `cadastrar_documento.php`:

```
$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT id,nome FROM cadastrar_loja ORDER BY nome DESC");
```

Em seguida faça o `<select>`:

```
<select class="form-control" name="txtNomeLoja" >
    <?php while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)) { ?>
      <option value=<?=$dados['id']?>> <?=$dados['nome']?> </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

O valor do `<select>` receberá o `id` da loja e para o usuário será exibido o `nome` da loja.

Comment: O.o se ele está começando pq utilizar o mysql_*(removido) ? precisa do `distinct` mesmo?

Comment: não entendi @rray?não usa-se distinct no mysql?

Comment: O nome da loja não deveria ter valores repetidos.

Comment: Valeeeeu, pegou certinho. Muito obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 3):

Boa Tarde Túlio,

Outra opção, e mais segura, seria utilizar o PDO.
Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=enderecodohost;dbname=nomedodb', $usuario, $senha);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, nome FROM lojas ORDER BY nome ASC');
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
<select name="lojas">
    <?php foreach($data as $row) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $row['id']; ?>"><?= $row['nome']; ?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

Você ainda pode passar PDO::FETCH_CLASS como parâmetro da função fetchAll(), e trabalhar com OO. Nesse caso seu retorno da query seriam objetos ao invés de arrays.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado cara, mas fiz sem PDO mesmo, mesmo assim, valeu, agregou conhecimento.